# jquery light box description text for each image

Tags: jquery, find, append, lightbox

I am working on a lightbox gallery.

I can create it from a dynamic database that stores images from a CMS.

What I can't do is to grab a text (also stored in a column of images databse) that describes each image and put it under the light box as description of the cliked image. Each image has its own text/description.

here u are the part of html/php code relative to the creation of the gallery:

```
<div class="gallery">
<?php foreach ($select as $sc): ?>
    <figure>
        <a class="go" href="<?php echo $sc['img_url'] ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $sc['thumb_ftp_path'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $sc['img_text'] ?>">
        </a>
    </figure>            
<?php endforeach ?>
```

As u can notice, I use the description text ($sc['img_text']) in order to dynamic write the "alt" attribute of each image.

For the light box, I am working on a script I found  on internet.

Here u are the jquery part relative to the creation of images'lightbox cliking the html "go" tag .

```
$('.go').click(function(e) {

// prevent default click event
e.preventDefault();

// grab href from clicked element
var image_href = $(this).attr("href");  

// determine the index of clicked trigger
var slideNum = $('.go').index(this);

// find out if #lightbox exists
if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {        
  // #lightbox exists
  $('#lightbox').fadeIn(300);
  // #lightbox does not exist - create and insert (runs 1st time only)
} else {                                
  // create HTML markup for lightbox window
  var lightbox =
      '<div id="lightbox">' +
      '<p>Close X</p>' +
      '<div id="description_text">'+ //div where insert the description of the image
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="slider">' +
      '<div class="nav">' +
      '<a class="prev slide-nav">prev</a>' +
      '<a class="next slide-nav">next</a>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

  //insert lightbox HTML into page
  $('body').append(lightbox);

  // fill lightbox with a hrefs in .gallery
  $('.gallery').find('figure > a').each(function() {
    var $href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#slider').append(
      '<img src="' + $href + '">'
    );
  });

}
```

Finally, the issue point. I can't use the variable $sc['img_text'] that leads the text in order to fill the div #description_text created by the jquery script when clicking on 'go' tag.

I tried te following way but it does't work:

```
$('.gallery').find('figure > img') {
    var $description_text = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#imgtext').append(
      '<p>' + $description_text + '</p>'
    );
```

});

Any suggestions please?

M.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself.
Here u are:

```
// fill lightbox/imgtext with alt attributes of a > img in .gallery
  $('.gallery').find('figure > a > img').each(function() {
    var $alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#imgtext').append('<p>' + $alt + '</p>');
  });
```

The attempt posted at the end of the question was wrong because the .find() method parameters was incomplete and I didn't code the parent path correctly.

With this now I am able to store the alt attribute of every image into a html "p" element and use them.

Matteo